# stm32f4-discovery with ov7670

Tags: embedded, stm32

I want to get view from ov7670 with stm32f4-discovery. i get a source code from internet and modify it. But now I get big problem with view i get. I can get true view with black, but other color show dark purple red. Just like http://tinyurl.com/bh49y9x. The first picture is that the ov7670 is cover with black paper on up part, second is right-up part, third is left-up part. I can't explain why the picture get from android is like that.

this is my code: https://github.com/ctc8631/ov7670 
now i use 176*144 & RGB565 to test, and transform raw data from android bitmap. Hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This must be caused by different number of columns associated to each line. I've faced similar problem. The simplest way is to use debugger and check range of data which is saved in image buffer.
For example in my case I had 144x174 instead of 144x176 (another workaround is to properly configure start and end registers in OV7670 but this also need some effort to find propoerly values)